# Isotope with Fancybox filtering

Tags: fancybox, filtering, gallery, categories

I implemented Isotope.js into my WordPress site. I use it to display gallery with Easy Fancybox plugin to add zooming functionality for images. Problem is with Isotope filtering. I added `rel` attribute to my images but when I filter categories Fancybox still cycles through all images.

I need to add `rel` attribute dynamically based on category I'm filtering. I'm struggling with this problem for 3 days now. I've read bunch of post, tried view things but still can't make it work.

Most of posts give solution with `data-fancybox-group` attribute but I can't use it I must use `rel` attribute (it doesn't work for me anyway).

Here's my WP code:

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms("polygraphy-categories"); 
        $count = count($terms); 
        if ( $count > 0 ){  
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  
                echo "<li><a class='filterbutton' href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</ul>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=polygraphy' ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div id="isotope-list">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "polygraphy-categories" );  
    $termsString = ""; 
    foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { 
        $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; 
    }
?> 
<div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> poli">
    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            echo '<a class="fancybox" href="' . $full_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
            echo '</a>';
        }
    ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile;  ?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And JS code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        var $container = $('#isotope-list'); 
        $container.isotope({ 
            itemSelector : '.poli', 
            layoutMode : 'masonry'
        });

        var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

        $optionLinks.click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
                return false;
            }
            var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
            $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');

            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I was told that this code should work but it doesn't:

```
$('.filterbutton').on("click", function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    if(selector == "*"){
        $(".fancybox").attr("rel", "gallery");
    } else{ 
        $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("rel", selector);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Check https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fancybox/ncVsViD2v9o/JE0DHYPuEOgJ if that helps

Comment: I already tried this. I dont know if its problem with Isotope version or what but your code doesnt work for me. I tried a lot of things and nothing works.